# plotting coordinate as a matrix matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have a set of coordinates, say `[(2,3),(45,4),(3,65)]` 
I need to plot them as a matrix is there anyway I can do this in matplotlib so I want it to have this sort of look https://i.stack.imgur.com/NctN2.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: My original answer used `ax.scatter`. There is a problem with this: If two points are side-by-side, `ax.scatter` may draw them with a bit of space in between, depending on the scale:

For example, with

```
data = np.array([(2,3),(3,3)])
```

Here is a zoomed-in detail:

[image]

So here is a alternative solution that fixes this problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([(2,3),(3,3),(45,4),(3,65)])
N = data.max() + 5

# color the background white (1 is white)
arr = np.ones((N,N), dtype = 'bool')
# color the dots black (0)
arr[data[:,1], data[:,0]] = 0

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.imshow(arr, interpolation='nearest', cmap = 'gray')
ax.invert_yaxis()
# ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

No matter how much you zoom in, the adjacent squares at (2,3) and (3,3) will remain side-by-side.

Unfortunately, unlike `ax.scatter`, using `ax.imshow` requires building an `N x N` array, so it could be more memory-intensive than using `ax.scatter`. That should not be a problem unless `data` contains very large numbers, however.